# Match any character before the last whitespace

Tags: java, regex

I want to match

```
String firstName = "CHRIS JAMES MR";
String prefix = "MR"; //mr Mr mR

firstName.matches("^(.*?)(?i)" + prefix + "$")
```

the current regex will return true even if it's

```
JOAmR
JOHN HOMR
```

wherein, it shouldn't.

So basically I'm trying to match

> [anyNumberOfChar][anyNumberOfWhiteSpaces][anyCaseOf
>   "MR"]

I'm using java's String.matches

Comment: Try `.matches("(.*?)\\s+(?i)" + prefix)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [word boundary](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) `\b`

[`^(.*?)(?i)\bMR$`](https://regex101.com/r/e70jCY/3)

`firstName.matches("^(.*?)(?i)\\b" + prefix + "$");`

[Demo](http://rextester.com/VDFL85262)